# Jump to next missing reference using auctex

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I'm using emacs + auctex for all my TeXing needs and I'm very satisfied with the workflow. However, there's one thing bothering me. Whenver I compile a document (possible consisting of multiple files) and there's a missing reference auctex prints this annoying message

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:MyMissingLabel' on page 42 undefined on input line 37.
```

and that's it. No shortcut for jumping to the missing reference, nada!
I'm aware that I could enable debugging of warnings, however, this is not really suitable in case the document produces other warnings which I don't want to debug¹.

I'd like to have a defun which cycles the point to the locations of the missing references. Thus I have not found anything online, maybe one of you guys can help?

Thanks in advance!

elemakil

[1] E.g. some packages report warnings when not loaded with a version number or something. I don't want to debug this. I'd like to correct my references!

Comment: Note that it states the error is on input line 37, so you can jump there with `M-g M-g 37`.

Answer (score 1):

The shorcuts in AUCTeX allow you to jump to an error.
The missing references are warnings.
You can activate your desired behavior by treating warnings as errors with `TeX-toggle-debug-warnings` which is bound to `C-c C-t C-w`.

Comment: As stated above this bears the problem that it cycles all warnings, not only the ones due to a missing reference.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but here's my take.  First, define the function

```lisp
(defun my-ignore-TeX-warnings (type file line text &rest more)
  (setq ref "LaTeX Warning: Reference")
  (not (string-match-p ref text)))
```

Then *customize* the two variables `TeX-ignore-warnings` and `TeX-suppress-ignored-warnings` - e.g.,

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(TeX-ignore-warnings 'my-ignore-TeX-warnings)
 '(TeX-suppress-ignored-warnings t))
```

*Note*: heed the warning above - i.e., you should only have *one* `custom-set-variables`.

Put the code into your `~/.emacs` or similar file.  Then, enable `TeX-toggle-debug-warnings` or through the menu **Command->TeXing options->Debug warnings**.

Cycling through errors with `` C-` `` will include undefined references.  One could extend the code above to also select undefined citations.

Yours,

Christian